# element.querySelector(".exampleClass") is not a function

Tags: javascript, css, dom, responsive-design, css-transforms

I am trying to build a responsive carousel and am getting an error in the following code.  I've tried using JQuery, other selection methods but they all return the same error.

I try to select the element here, first my accessing its parent element

```
     var carousel = $('#carousel');
     var container = carousel.querySelector('.carousel-container');
```

The about code returns and ERROR that carousel.querySelector is not a function.

Which creates a problem, and also screws up the resizing function below:

```
  function slideTo(index){
      index = index < 0 ? totalItems -1 : index >= totalItems ? 0 : index;
      container.style = container.style.transform = 'translate(-' + (index * percent) + '%, 0)';
       currentIndex = index;
   }
```

Container.style  in the third line of the function returns an ERROR that I cannot set a property on container.style  as it is "undefined"

I REALLY just need to be able to add the CSS "transform : translate" property to the container element.

I am at a loss for things to try... would really appreciate some feedback!

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and native calls. Try `document.getElementById('carousel').querySelector('.carousel-container')`.

Comment: THANK YOU! that worked!   I was scratching my head to long on that one.... thanks so much!

Answer (score 10):

`querySelector` is a native JS method, and `carousel` is a `jQuery` object. If you are using `jQuery`, there is no reason to be using `queryselector`.

**jQuery**

```
var carousel = $('#carousel'); //jQuery object
var container = carousel.find('.carousel-container'); //jquery object of carousel-container
```

**DOM**

```
var domCarousel=carousel.find('.carousel-container')[0];
```

*which is roughly equivalent to*

```
domCarousel=document.getElementById('carousel').querySelector('.carousel-container');
```